# Can't install discord.py "Failed to build yarl multidict" error

Tags: python, cmd, discord

So I tried with the usual

```
pip install discord
```

and got

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, multidict which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I even tried downloading the wheel and installing directly from the file but I got the same error. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to downgrade your python version to Python 3.8.6, which has all the wheels that you need.